# Is my tax software correct when it automatically deducts $3000 from my carried forward cap gain tax losses despite I get a refund?

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-loss

I am ending up with a refund for 2021 due to child credits but my tax software automatically deducts $3000 from my carry forward amount anyway (see line 7), is this correct? If I do not need to pay taxes, why is it doing this? Here are my numbers for 2021 tax year[image: 1040 page 1] [image: 1040 page 2]

Comment: That you get a refund doesn't mean that you are not paying taxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Your carried forward capital loss will be applied to capital gains if available, or up to $3K will be applied to ordinary income, until the capital loss carry-forward is exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how it supposed to work.

The carryover is used to offset capital gains, but $3,000 of it can also reduce ordinary income. That $3,000 reduction decreased your taxable income, thus  decreasing your taxes, and increasing your refund.

The tax software made sure that this wasn't missed. This is one of the big benefits of using tax software, it carries over items from year to year. It remembers how many times you took the college tuition credit, it  remembers the points you paid on the mortgage. It remembers what your state refund was last year.

Comment: How does it increase my refund? If I remove my capital loss, the -3000 will go away but the refund generated by the software stays the same. How does this work?

Comment: Would you happen to know, if I amortize the rental that I reported, it also doesn't seem to increase the refund. How come? How do some things seem to affect it and others not?

Comment: @user1422331 your income is fairly low and for MFJ you're just not paying any tax at all (see line 24). So reducing your income further doesn't matter since you're already at 0. But that doesn't matter, as long as you have income to deduct the $3K from - you have to deduct it.

Comment: TY littleadv, I just wanted to make sure that I am not missing anything so I don't "kick myself" down the road. Based on the other questions I asked and this one, it looks like that I must deduct the $3000 and there isn't much I can do to increase the refund and this is the best I can do.